# Android Studio with libGdx(Java) - Music work on android emulator but not on desktop

Tags: java, android, libgdx, desktop

Here's my code:

```
music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("music.mp3"));
music.setLooping(true);
music.setVolume(0.1f);
music.play();
```

When i run the app on android emulator everything work as it should and when i run the app on desktop there's no music. What should i do?

Comment: Libgdx support .mp3 file, may be you set volume 0.1f so your music is not audible but playing ? check your system(dekstop) volume ?

Comment: Nope, i use the same amount of volume when i start the android emulator both the desktop app. I also tried to set the volume to 1.0f in the code and 100% in my desktop and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

After another searching, I finally found an answer! this happens because I have on my computer an username that isn't in english. All i needed to do was to add  `System.setProperty("user.name","seconduser");`
to the DesktopLauncher code. The final code should look like this:

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    System.setProperty("user.name","seconduser");
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    new LwjglApplication(new GameName(), config);
}
```

Hope it will help someone else.